# How do I find the angle given the mass, the acceleration and the force acted on a body?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration

### My Issue

I have the **mass**, the horizontal **acceleration** and a **force** that acts on a body. The force forms an **angle** $\alpha$ of unknown degrees with the x-axis. I would like to know how I can find the angle $\alpha$ formed by the force and in which way the angle is connected with the horizontal acceleration.

### What I tried

This formula calculates the horizontal acceleration given the force $F$, the mass $m$ and angle formed by the force $\alpha$:

$$a_x = \frac{F}{m} \cos(\alpha)$$

By inverting it, I can easily calculate the cosine of the angle $\alpha$:

$$cos(\alpha) = a_x\frac{m}{F}$$

However, I'm not sure about how can I revert the cosine of the angle to find its degrees.

### Questions

What am I missing? In which way is the angle $\alpha$ connected with the horizontal acceleration?

Comment: The reverse operation of $\cos$ is $\arccos$. Apply that to both sides and you get $\alpha$.

Comment: This question is confusing. If the force acts completely in the x direction it makes no sense to talk about an angle other than 0

Comment: European and American punctuation on units.

Comment: The question is not properly stated.  Is the TOTAL force 10N?

Comment: Yes, it is. Sorry for that.

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/168577/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the total force is $10~\text{N}$, the $7~\text{kg}$ mass is accelerated by $1.0~\text{m/s^2}$, so it is experiencing $7~\text{N}$ force in x-direction.  Therefore, $F_x = .7F$. The angle is roughly $45^\circ$.